# How can I format phone numbers from a Google Form in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form which sends responses to a Google spreadsheet. One of the form inputs is a phone number.

In Google Sheets, I have formatted the column containing the phone numbers as `"###-###-####"`. This works properly for existing data but new responses are not formatted.

What can I do so that new responses have the same format applied as the existing column?

Answer (score 1):

Form responses are always inserted in newly created rows that cannot be formatted in advance.

The usual recipe to work around the issue is to **Insert > Sheet** and use a formula in cell `A1` to copy all responses, like this:

```
={ 'Form Responses 1'!A1:Z }
```

The new sheet can be formatted and the formats will be applied to newly arriving form responses in addition to existing responses.

If you are using formulas to process the data, point those formulas to the new sheet instead of the form responses sheet.